# How to create this (see image) repetition effect in adobe illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, illustrator-effects

I'm wondering since a long time how this (see images) effect is created in Adobe Illustrator.

It looks like the blend tool but I've been trying to accomplish it but it seems like it's done with an other kind or repetition tool. Or it seems to be done with the transformation tool, but also via this way I can't get it anywhere close like this.

Does any one knows with which technique this is able to accomplish?

[image: http://fingersports.blogspot.com/2010_12_01_archive.html]

[image: https://www.searchsystem.co/post/166610446414/author-client-title-medium-year]
[image: https://www.flickr.com/photos/blankaposters/5257486764/in/photostream/]

Comment: offset and object nudge?

Answer (score 1):

Yes I got it, it is done with the offset path and nudge, thanks @joojaa .
[image: Design by Typefool @ instagram]